# i have a table of (fillup_record) i want to sum all values under column name (Total_Cost) but for a particular car name

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 public Double getCostt(String a) {
        openDatabase();
        Double price = null;
        Cursor cursor0=myDataBase.rawQuery("Select*FROM fillup_record WHERE Vehicle_Name='"+a+"'", null); //getting all values where vehicle name wi
```

> in my databasehelper class and return a one double value to my activity?thanks in advance

```
        cursor0.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor0.isAfterLast())
        {Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(Total_Cost) FROM fillup_record GROUP BY Vehicle_Name", null);
            price = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3));
            cursor0.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor0.close();
        myDataBase.close();
        return price;
    }
}
```